# Multiple hidden input types in td causing height issues

Tags: html

```
<input type="hidden" name=" " id="" value=" <%=  ">
<input type="hidden" name=" " id="" value=" <%=  ">
<input type="hidden" name=" " id="" value=" <%=  ">
```

After all the hidden input types there is one more line which is getting rendered in the table. but the input type is coming just half the size of td. And there is empty bottom space in td. Thus, between each rows there are empty spaces. please suggest something for this

Comment: Please post your code to do something.

Comment: What's with the unclosed .net tags?